# Git for Windows equivalent for open current directory command

Tags: git, shell, command-line-interface, git-bash

I am using the Git for Windows "git bash" command line on Windows and can't seem to find an equivalent in it for the open current directory command "cmd ." I can't find any documentation but if someone can point me to a list of commands for Git for Windows or let me know what the equivalent is I would appreciate it.

Comment: I need to amend my question I meant the "open ." command.

Comment: Do you mean open a cmd prompt? Do you have a link illustrating the open cmd command you have in mind?

Comment: I would like to open a directory with windows file manager (GUI) from the command line. In the research I did the typical command is "open ." but when I type that in to the command line I get "sh.exe : open: command not found"

Comment: An example is I have a directory labeled "projects" and I would like to use the command line prompt to open this directory using my operating systems native file manager. Commands like mkdir, touch, mv, rm all seems to work the same way but "open ." does not.

Comment: "open a directory with windows file manager (GUI)" I still don't knwo what that would mean for Git. Do you want an msysgit shell from the Windows explorer current path?

Comment: I think I'm over-complicating this sorry. Lets say I have a file called index.html and from the command line I want to use a command that would pull up this file up in sublime text which is my default text editor. How would I do that?

Comment: You say in a comment that you want to open the current directory in the Windows GUI (Windows Explorer), but that's not at all clear from your question. Can you update the question? Also, if you open a `.html` file, it will probably open it in your web browser by default. If you want to open a file in Sublime Text, you should be able to type the name of the Sublime Text executable with the file name as an argument. You can set up a function, alias, or wrapper script that invokes Sublime Text (since the path is likely to be something ugly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lets say I have a file called index.html and from the command line I want to use a command that would pull up this file up in sublime text which is my default text editor. How would I do that?

Simply define an alias (if you are in a CMD session, started with [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat).
In Windows, that would be:

```
doskey sbt=start "Sublime Text 3" "C:\path\to\Sublime_Text_x64\sublime_text.exe" $*
```

In a git bash shell:

```
alias sbt='"/c/path/to/SublimeText/sublime_text.exe"'
```

Then type `sbt yourFile`, and it will open directly in Sublime Text.

Comment: Nice, extend this answer so the OP can also start a new terminal. Simply make an alias to the location of MySysGit, +1

Comment: Note: I have tested this with the laster Git for Windows 2.4.1 bash (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases). It seems to work just fine.

Comment: I'm getting closer to answering my question. So I failed in creating an alias, not sure why, but then I found a tutorial where I create a file called .bashrc in my root directory. I then added the following string of code to that file sub='"/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe"' and now when I type sub, sublime text open automatically. Now I need to figure out how to use a similar technique to open directories in The Windows File Manager from the git bash command line.

Comment: Figured out why  I couldn't get the alias to work earlier. I needed to place the file path in double quotes wrapped in single quotes. Example: alias sbt='"/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe"'

Comment: @Javi Yes, if your path has space, it needs double-quotes indeed. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash under Windows (whether it's installed via a Git installer, Cygwin, or something similar), you should be able to open the current directory in Windows Explorer by typing

```
cmd /c start .
```

`cmd` is the Windows command line program.  `/c` tells it to use use the rest of the command line as a command to be executed.  `start` opens the specified argument; if it's a directory it opens it (by default) in Windows Explorer. You can also use this to open images, documents, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

On my native Linux system you'd simply call

```
gnome-terminal .
```

or

```
konsole
```

or

```
xterm
```

I hope MySysGit supports at least one of these...

Comment: What is the output of  `echo $PATH` on MySysGit?

Comment: It looks like it returns the file paths for all the directories in the current directory.

Comment: Are any commands like `awk`, `sed`, `tr` available? You can find out using `which sed` for example.

Comment: They all work, the return commands I'm not familiar with. Which sed returns /bin/sed

Comment: Lets say I have a file called index.html and from the command line I want to use a command that would pull up this file up in sublime text which is my default text editor. How would I do that?

Comment: First check the location of `sublime`, if it's supported by your bash emulator. Do this using `which sublime`. If this command outputs a path such as `/usr/bin/sublime` then you can simply do `sublime index.html`. Otherwise you'll have to look for other commands like `gnome-open` or something.