# How can I configure git to open the relevant COMMIT_EDITMSG in sublime text 3?

Tags: git, bash, sublimetext3, commit

On a windows machine.

I have run git:

```
config --global core.editor "[path to sublime_text.exe] -w"
```

and sublime text does in fact open when I make commit, however instead of opening the relevant `COMMIT_EDITMSG` it opens up a new blank tab titled `"$@"`. I then have to open up the correct `COMMIT_EDITMSG` within sublime text before saving it.

I am hoping there is a way to set up git with sublime text 3 so that I can skip the manual navigation and the relevant `COMMIT_EDITMSG` opens whenever I run git commit.

Comment: Would adding the -n option help? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25255676/6309)

Comment: Did you install cmdline features in sublime?

Comment: @VonC 

My original command included -n but that didn't seem to help either, it just opened a second blank window in sublime also titled "$@".

Comment: @NickVolynkin 

I just read over the command line features in sublime here:

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command-line

but I am not able to see how this will help me with my problem. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @JayMoontra instead of calling directly `sublime_ext.exe`, could you try (as I did in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30443796/6309) `start "Sublime Text 3" "C:\path\to\Sublime_Text_x64\sublime_text.exe -n -w"` (with or without the `-n`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install the [GitSavvy](https://github.com/divmain/GitSavvy) plugin for SublimeText3 - you can then do all this inside sublime - with [lots of other benefits](https://github.com/divmain/GitSavvy#highlights), too.